# Powerpoint/VSTO + WPF + threading, why weak performance or weak responsiveness?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, vsto, responsive

I am developing add-in to PowerPoint. I am inserting wpf control  inside winforms/office taskpane control.

(Almost) everything  works fine, but I have a problem with threading/wpf control responsiveness/performance.

When I run some long running method in new thread it takes a lot of time to complete it (about 5-6 minutes), but control is responsive and my progress control works fine (it appears and all labels are upgraded properly and smoothly ). When I run it without creating new thread, it is completed in about 15 seconds, but progress view is not shown at all, PowerPoint just hangs for around 15 seconds (till end of method and moving to another view).

code 1, good responsiveness, terrible performance (5-6 minutes):

```
public void Prepare()
{
    Thread myNewThread = null;
    if (AuditType == AuditGeneralType.ContentAudit)
    {
        myNewThread = new Thread(() => Auditor.AuditContentMD(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation, this, SessionData.Settings));
    }
    else if (AuditType == AuditGeneralType.FormattingAudit)
    {
         myNewThread = new Thread(() => Auditor.AuditFormattingMD(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation, this, SessionData.Settings));
    }
    myNewThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

    myNewThread.Start();
}
```

code 2 (no responsiveness, very good performance - 15 seconds):

```
public void Prepare()
{
    if (AuditType == AuditGeneralType.ContentAudit)
    {
        Auditor.AuditContentMD(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation, this, SessionData.Settings);
    }
    else if (AuditType == AuditGeneralType.FormattingAudit)
    {
        Auditor.AuditFormattingMD(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation, this, SessionData.Settings);
    }
}
```

What should I change to have a code that will result in:

- high performance
- high responsiveness
- smoothness

?